# Working with dates & timestamps how to get yesteday. today etc

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, timestamp, google-sheets

So I'm new to scripting and still trying to learn, so be gentle.
I've read over the forum and some posts, looking for the answer, but I can't quite work it out.

I'd like to see if a timestamp date in a sheet is from X days ago, any time within day x, and do that with other days pretty much today to about 31 days away.
I've had a script before where it finds if it's older than a certain date. But I'm thinking that the reason my equal's isn't finding matches in the data because it's looking for that exact date and **time**. not just date.

I've tried playing with getDate, but for example, if i do get date now. I get 4, I minus 7, for 7 days ago, I get -3. So that method is no good. Here is my code so far, but lots of it is me playing and trying to work out dates, etc (just thought I'd post workings so far, so you could see that I have tried).

```
      function snapshot() {

    var dateColumn = 2;
    var findColumn = 4;
   var toFind = "Yes - Complete (going ahead)";
   var daysWorth = 16;
   //  var daysWorth1 = 17;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses');
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var valuesLength = values.length;
  Logger.log("1) "+valuesLength);

  var today = new Date().getTime();
  var gap = new Date(today - daysWorth*24*60*60*1000);
  Logger.log("2) today  " +today);
 // Logger.log("gap  "  +gap);
//  Logger.log("today  " +today.getTime());
 // Logger.log("gap  "  +gap.getTime());
//  Logger.log ("gap in milli " + daysWorth*24*60*60*1000 - daysWorth1*24*60*60*1000);
 // Logger.log ("gap in milli " + daysWorth1*24*60*60*1000);
  var test = today / 1*24*60*60*1000;


  var counter = 1;
  var completed = 0;
  var attempted = 0;

  Logger.log("3) "+values[counter][dateColumn - 1].getDate());
  Logger.log("4) "+today);
  Logger.log("4a) A day "+1*24*60*60*1000);
  Logger.log("4b)  "+   test);
  while (counter < valuesLength){

   if (values[counter][dateColumn - 1].getDate() == today && values[counter][findColumn - 1] == toFind)
    {completed++;}
   if (values[counter][dateColumn - 1].getDate() == today && values[counter][findColumn - 1] != toFind)
   {attempted++;}

      counter++


  Logger.log("5) "+completed);
  Logger.log("6) "+attempted);

  }
}
```

thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try to play with the getTime() that give you a value in millisecond much more easier to manipulate. setHour() and setMinutes() may also help you to qualify in a better way what you are testing. To better understand Date() in js you should read the dedicated page in [W3school](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) site.
Anyway here your code with little changes it should work now.

```
function snapshot() {
  var dateColumn = 0;
  var findColumn = 2;
  var toFind = "comment";  // I made some change to feet to my spreadsheet
  var daysWorth = 336;  // I made some change to feet to my spreadsheet

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses');
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var today = new Date();
  var thisMorning = today;
  thisMorning.setHours(0);
  thisMorning.setMinutes(0);

  var gap = new Date().setTime(thisMorning.getTime() - daysWorth*24*60*60*1000);

  var completed = 0;
  var attempted = 0;

  for(var counter in values){
     var testDate = new Date(values[counter][dateColumn]);
//    Logger.log("row: "+counter+" date time is: "+testDate.getTime());
//    Logger.log("(testDate - today) time: "+testDate.getTime()-thisMorning.getTime());
  // values[counter][dateColumn].getDate() == today // this will never work as "today" is right now.

    if (testDate > thisMorning && values[counter][findColumn] == toFind)
    {completed++;}
    if (testDate > thisMorning && values[counter][findColumn] != toFind)
    {attempted++;}
  }
  Logger.log("today we had: "+completed+" completed and: "+attempted+" attempted");

  // change "thisMorning" to an other date to do an other check exemple with gap
  for(var counter in values){
    var testDate = new Date(values[counter][dateColumn]);
    if (testDate > gap && values[counter][findColumn] == toFind)
    {completed++;}
    if (testDate > gap && values[counter][findColumn] != toFind)
    {attempted++;}
  }
  Logger.log("since "+daysWorth+" we had: "+completed+" completed and: "+attempted+" attempted");
}
```

Comment: Hi @Harold
Thank you for the reply.
I did have a play with get time, I guess the problem I was having was getting it to specify all day.

Will try your code now and see.
many thanks

Comment: Have just tested the script and to does work to count dates > a certain date. But the main issue I'm having is how to get all entries for a certain date, using today as a compare. 
I.E How many for attempts/completed for an entire 24 hour period X days away.
The .setHour & .setMinute has given me something to explore.
many thanks

Comment: Using your suggestion, I added another time var (endGap) and changed gap to startGap. This enabled me to select the a whole day of my choicce X days ago :) Thank you very much